# wordpress how to 3 columns post list and columns wrap

Tags: wordpress, post

I am trying to load a WordPress blog list with the following structure.

this is my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdaKs.png)

```
(div class="left-wrap)
post-1
post-4
post-7

(div class="right-wrap)
post-2
post-3
post-5
post-6
(/div)
```

POST 1 | POST 2 , POST 3

POST 4 | POST 5 , POST 6

POST 7 | POST 8 , POST 7

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Populate the post array like the below and separately loop through for the left and right section

```
<?php 
    $posts = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"];
    $left_array = [];
    $right_array = [];
    foreach($posts as $key => $post){
        if(($key+1) % 3 == 1){
          $left_array[] = $post;
        }
        else{
           $right_array[] = $post;
        }
    }

    print_r($left_array);
    print_r($right_array);

    ?>
```

**OUTPUT**

**LEFT ARRAY**

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => four
    [2] => seven
    [3] => ten
)
```

**RIGHT ARRAY**

```
Array
(
    [0] => two
    [1] => three
    [2] => five
    [3] => six
    [4] => eight
    [5] => nine
)
```